# Project 'MyProject' requires a reference to version '14.0.0.0' of assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2010 and a VB Project that had a reference to Microsoft.Interop.Excel 12.0. Well recently I changed the reference version to 14.0. That was actually a mistake and now I need to bump it back down to version 12.0. However I get this error in my project now...

Project 'MyProject' requires a reference to version '14.0.0.0' of assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel', but references version '12.0.0.0'
of assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'.

I tried removing references and adding the com object to, but no avail. Does anyone have clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after I finally realized there was a .dll in my Solution that had a reference to the Interop.Excel 14.0.0.0.